# LibGDX positioning issue with fill viewport

Tags: libgdx, viewport, aspect-ratio, scene2d

I'm making a game in libGDX. In my menu screens I used to have a stretch viewport for the stage but now I want to maintain the aspect ratio so I switched to a fill viewport with a fixed height.

So the problem I am having is with the buttons that used to be at the edge of the screen. For example I had a button in one screen with an x position of 0 and now (depending on device) it can end up outside the viewport bounds. So I was wondering how I solve this using a fill viewport or similar. Is there anyone who has a similar issue and how did you solve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
viewport.getLeftGutterWidth()
```

This will return the width of the left "black bar". A black bar appears, when the viewport is smaller than the actual window. In your case, this can never happen, because it's a `FillViewport`.

Depending on your aspect ratio, `viewport.getLeftGutterWidth()` will return either `0`, in case the viewport got over-extended on the y-axis, or it has a negative value in case it over-extended on the x-axis.

So what you are looking for is `Math.abs(viewport.getLeftGutterWidth())` for the x-value of the left-most visible coordinate.